# difference between mvn install:install-file and direct copy to local repo

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have maven's local repo without one artifact, which I have in another local repo (I made it for separate project).

I have observed a strange behavior for me: if I copy whole folder with missing artifact from one repo to another, it still fails to find it. The only option will be to call `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/path/to/file`.

What does `install-file` doing besides copying file and recreating a folder tree?

Answer (score 2):

It's arranging the metadata that comes with the file in .m2. Look into it and you'll see many xml files that help maven arrange and index the files.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Don't forget checksum files and it' possible to use the generatePOM option to create POM files for standalone artifacts. All in all you are best advised to use Maven.